# Java programming - Abstract class

Tags: java

```
abstract class Concept {
    public void Mymethod() {
        System.out.println("this is concrete method");
    }

    abstract public void junk();
}

class king extends Concept {

    public void junk() {
        System.out.println("this is abstract method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        king n = new king();
        n.junk();
    }
}
```

Please check the error in this. While compiling this, I was hit with the following issue:

```
Error: Main method not found in class Concept, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Comment: Your main is in class "king" not in class Concept as the error would imply.  When you run it, you need to specify the class name to run containing main.

Comment: Each public class should be in it's own file you can't have two classes like this in one file

Answer (score 0):

Separate your codes in two different files:

File: `Concept.java`

```
package myPackage;

public abstract class Concept {
    public void Mymethod() {
        System.out.println("this is concrete method");
    }

    abstract public void junk();
}
```

and

File: `king.java`:

```
package myPackage;
public class king extends Concept {

    public void junk() {
        System.out.println("this is abstract method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        king n = new king();
        n.junk();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using eclipse to run ,

right click on the classfile>RunConfiguration>select the class u need to run (in the left pane)>select run/apply

Answer (score 0):

You missed `public` keyword. Everything else is correct.When you are running your program,JVM searches for a public class and it does not find one so it fails with this message.

```
abstract class Concept {
    public void Mymethod() {
        System.out.println("this is concrete method");
    }

    abstract public void junk();
}

public class king extends Concept {

    public void junk() {
        System.out.println("this is abstract method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        king n = new king();
        n.junk();
    }
}
```

Output

```
this is abstract method
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which main class you are using. For example I just tried this in eclipse and it works without any change if I specify in the running configurations that you have king as your main class. If you make a jar runnable package, you are also able to run it. Of course your manifest file should specify king as your main class. Word of advice, you should follow camel notation for class names. You can use king but King would be better. You don't need the public keyword for the class declaration.

Answer (score -2):

You need to have the main method in a class at a separate file, and your entry point should be that class